# Storing image file on stellar network

Tags: stellar-core, operations, data

I am trying to insert an image into Stellar private network. I have gone through all the operations but did not find anything.

Any new update with Stellar protocol version 12?

Answer (score 2):

Stellar is not suited for file storage and serving. Storing arbitrary binary data is possible, but it's slow and expensive. Use something like IPFS or cloud platform for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

As Orbit Lens already said, Stellar is not suited for this purpose. However your best options for storing data are:

- ManageData Operation: 64 byte key + 64 byte value, but will require a 0.5 XLM reserve per entry. To eliminate the reserve requirement you could delete the entries right away but since Stellar is a state machine that (other than e.g. bitcoin) does not need the whole complete transaction history for progress, that data will only be stored by full archive nodes in long term. Besides I remember a year ago there have been discussions to deprecate the ManageData functionality at all.
- Transaction Memo: 32 byte (again, transaction history is only stored by full archive nodes)
- SetOptions(HomeDomain) Operation: 32 byte (same downside)

Comment: okay.I have tried to  data persist by ManageDataOperation but am looking for to image persist.